# Sharepoint Drag and Drop hangs and keeps loading

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to upload files on a sharepoint farm through drag and drop. For some users it works and for some it hangs. Loader icon just keeps on loading and nothing happens. If I cancel, file is gone. Can somebody please provide the cause and applicable solution? and it only happens on IE. Other browsers are OK with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you get errors in the **console**? -> Developer Tools (hit F12) -> **console** tab

Also, still in the developer tool, do you see any request with a 4xx or 5xx status code under the **Network** tab after dropping the file?

Maybe you already gave a solution when you said that it works in different browser :) - but I understand that sometimes the users do not have a different browser other than IE due to Group Policy